# Can't test Mapbox-gl due to 'TypeError: map.on is not a function'

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

We're using Mapbox in our project for a couple of months now. This project uses Create React App (CRA) with Typescript. As we started, we immediately ran into some problems with testing components > long story short; when we ran tests we got the error "window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function". There was a proposed workaround to mock Mapbox in setupTests.ts which did not work for us.

The question here is: is it us, or something to do with Mapbox? + does anyone know how to get Mapbox tests working?

I've also opened an issue on the Mapbox GitHub page and created a demonstration repository so you can reproduce the error.